# ckeditor and codemirror, conflicts with plugin with same name

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, codemirror

I am trying to use both [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) and [codemirror](http://codemirror.net/)

The problem is because ckeditor has a plugin also called [codemirrow](http://ckeditor.com/addon/codemirror)

Is there anyway to make them work together?

Comment: aren't you trying to set up one and the same thing two times?

Comment: Yes sadly, I started with ckeditor used in Opencart as default. But I needed to use codemirror to format native XML, ckeditor is restricted to HTML only.

Comment: so why don't you just use codemirror ?

Comment: Because I need both, otherwise gladly get rig of ckeditor. Anyway is there a way to encapsulate a the plugin just that it doesn't cause conflict with the same name?

Comment: will be complicated.
I would have a idea to for example use an iFrame and sandbox the tools or use different names ( or initialize both into different objects )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically... rename one of the plugins. Change directory name and the name of registered plugin in the line:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( someNewName, { ... } );
```

Then check whether the plugin refers to itself somewhere inside of own body via `editor.plugins`. Correct it if necessary (most likely there's nothing like that).

If there are some dialogs with redundant names, repeat the process by changing:

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( someNewName, function( editor ) { ... } );
```

Finally, change your configuration file so it loads the renamed plugin. That's all. That was easy, wasn't it? ;)